# Canon printer advanced preferences missing

Tags: windows-10, drivers, printer

I have a Windows 10 computer and a Canon printer (MF244dw, but I suspect this issue affects many other Canon printers). The preferences window for the printer has many settings, covering paper weight, toner usage, etc. (First image below)

On another new computer also running Windows 10 I have connected the same printer and installed the drivers from the Canon website (Their description of the drivers being *[Windows 64bit] MF249dw/MF247dw/MF244dw MFDrivers (UFR II / PCL / FAX / ScanGear)*). But the printing preferences on this computer are far more basic, missing several settings that I use regularly. (Second image below)

Any idea what I can do to get the fully featured printing preferences on the newer computer?

**Detailed preferences window:**

[image: Screen capture of detailed printer settings]

**New preferences window:**

[image: Screen capture of basic printer settings]

Comment: What happens when you click the *Advanced* button? Is there an option to *always* show the *Advanced* dialog?

Comment: @DrMoishePippik There are only a few more basic settings in the "Advanced" popup, just paper size, number of copies, etc. It isn't much help, I'm afraid.

Comment: To be shown the full print dialogue: `CTRL`+`SHIFT`+`P` > Highlight printer > Preferences

Comment: @JW0914 Perhaps I was unclear. The above screenshot _is_ what I see when opening printer preferences.

Comment: @andypaxo did you perform the first step (key combo)? Print options and print dialogue are not the same things.  It's not possible for that options box to be shown for the actual printer's properties (`Control Panel\Hardware and Sound\Devices and Printers`), as those advanced properties come from the printer's driver.  The box you're being shown is the newer slimmed-down print options for Windows - they are not the printer's properties.

Comment: @JW0914 Thanks for your patience in helping figure this out. Where should I use that key combo? I've tried it in Word, Acrobat etc., in the Printers and Scanners settings in Windows, and whilst using the other printer properties dialog. Nothing happens in any of those cases.

Comment: @andypaxo That key combo will bring up the older style print dialogue box and works in almost all, if not all, applications.  The only other thing I can think of is the port for the printer was changed in Printer Properties.  Reinstalling the print driver should resolve the issue, else you may want to contact Canon tech support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found the answer after a lot of guesswork.

- Open the Windows *Printers & Scanners* settings window
- Go to *Manage* for the printer in question
- In *Printer Properties* (not printing preferences), under the Advanced tab, a number of different drivers are available to choose from.

After installing the drivers from the Canon website, this was set to "Canon UFR II B/W Class Driver". I changed it to "Canon MF240 Series UFRII LT", and now the detailed preferences window is available.

I imagine that the same would apply to other Canon printers and even other manufacturers. Some trial and error is required... in this case there were four likely looking options to choose from and no particular way to tell which one was correct other than trying them all.

The relevant properties page:

[image: Windows printer properties advanced tab]

Comment: When the drivers were installed, did it not add more than one printer to Devices and Printers?  The LT driver is always assigned to it's own printer AFAIK, with a second printer installed and assigned a different driver.  If the driver is only installing one printer, you may want to reach out to Canon Tech Support to understand what exactly is going on _(if Canon is defaulting it to the B/W driver, there's likely a reason, or at the minimum, documentation as to why)_

Comment: @JW0914 Just went and checked back. You're right, there are two printers installed for the same physical printer. Unfortunately, having messed around with them now, I couldn't say what driver they were both using originally. I can say with confidence, though, that the one with "LT" in the name was _not_ using the LT driver by default, which seems weird.